# Doing an accurate text replacement with sed in braces?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to modify an xcode project file from the command line as part of a build process.

I want to change:

```
...
SystemCapabilities = {
  com.apple.InAppPurchase = {
    enabled = 0;
  };
};
...
```

to this:

```
...
SystemCapabilities = {
  com.apple.InAppPurchase = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
};
...
```

The simplest solution I can use to solve this is by simply running:

```
sed -i '' 's/enabled = 0/enabled = 1/' myapp.pbxproj
```

However, I feel like this is kind of dangerous because even though it works, there could be an issue if there is an `enabled = 0` somewhere else in the file. Is there a better way to use `sed` to make sure I only target that specific instance of `enabled = 0` that is in `com.apple.InAppPurchase` object?

Comment: `sed`  is a plaintext tool. Normally you'd want to use a tool that understand your specific format, e.g. `xmlstarlet` for XML or `jq` for JSON.  Is this some kind of well known format?

Comment: It is basically the project file for `iOS` apps. I might need to do this build process in a programming language to find some parser then instead of a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an address range to tell sed to only apply the substitution between `com.apple.InAppPurchase` and `}`:

```
sed '/com\.apple\.InAppPurchase/,/}/s/enabled = 0/enabled = 1/'
```

Comment: Just as an FYI to anyone else who is doing this on macOS and needs to do this in a file, you need to pass `-i ''` to `sed` for some reason. Full command I'm running is `sed -i '' '/com\.apple\.InAppPurchase/,/}/s/enabled = 0/enabled = 1/' myapp.pbxproj`

Comment: You can also pass `-i .bak` and you'll get a backup.